# Problem with Elsevier template (add MSC mathematics class subject)

Tags: elsarticle

I am writing my paper using the Elsevier template provided here https://www.ctan.org/pkg/els-cas-templates/. I don't know how to add Mathematics Subject Classification. The working I'm writing currently looks like this

```
\documentclass[a4paper,fleqn]{cas-sc}

\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\usepackage{amsthm,amssymb,tikz-cd}

\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[section]
\newtheorem{example}{Example}[section]

\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}[section]
\newtheorem{proposition}{Proposition}[section]
\newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}[section]

\makeatother

%%%Author macros
\def\tsc#1{\csdef{#1}{\textsc{\lowercase{#1}}\xspace}}
\tsc{WGM}
\tsc{QE}
\tsc{EP}
\tsc{PMS}
\tsc{BEC}
\tsc{DE}
%%%

\begin{document}
\let\WriteBookmarks\relax
\def\floatpagepagefraction{1}
\def\textpagefraction{.001}
\shorttitle{Ordering of matrices by precede operator}
\shortauthors{Amirul Aizad Ahmad Fuad and Tahir Ahmad}

\title [mode = title]{Ordering of matrices by precede operator}                      

\author[1]{Amirul Aizad Ahmad Fuad}[type=editor,
                        orcid=0000-0003-0819-4922]
\cormark[1]
\fnmark[1]
\ead{aaizad3@graduate.utm.my}

\address[1]{Department of Mathematical Sciences, Faculty of Science, Universiti Teknologi Malaysia, 81310 Johor Bahru, Malaysia}

\author[2]{Tahir Ahmad}
\cormark[2]
\fnmark[2]
\ead{tahir@ibnusina.utm.my}

\address[2]{Centre for Sustainable Nanomaterials, Ibnu Sina Institute for Scientific and Industrial Research, Universiti Teknologi Malaysia, 81310 Johor Bahru, Malaysia}

\cortext[cor1]{Corresponding author}
\cortext[cor2]{Principal corresponding author}

\begin{abstract}
We investigated partial orders on a set of real square matrices and introduced a new order relation based on several function compositions. We also established some results as the consequences of the new partial order on square matrices and symmetric matrices. 
\end{abstract}

\begin{keywords} 
  Matrix partial order \sep Precede partial order \sep Symmetric matrices 
\end{keywords}


\maketitle

\section{Introduction and Motivation}
\label{sec:intro}

\end{document}
```

which produces:

[image]

I want to add MSC like this (highlighted):

[image]

Comment: Maybe you should choose a more friendly publisher. There are plenty of Diamond Open Access journals in mathematics...

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
\begin{keywords}
\MSC 15A09 \sep 15A57 \sep 15A24
Matrix partial order \sep Precede partial order \sep Symmetric matrices
\end{keywords}
```

See below for the documentation (extracted from the "cas-sc-template.tex" file in the link you [provided](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/els-cas-templates/)):

```
\begin{keyword}
%% keywords here, in the form: keyword \sep keyword

%% PACS codes here, in the form: \PACS code \sep code

%% MSC codes here, in the form: \MSC code \sep code
%% or \MSC[2008] code \sep code (2000 is the default)

\end{keyword}
```